# How to remove a menu item added by WooCommerce Smart Coupons from the MyAccount navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

**Situation:**

When using [WooCommerce Smart Coupons](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/smart-coupons/) a new menu item is added to the 'My Account' navigation in WooCommerce.

---

**Question:**

I would like to remove this menu item.

---

**Problem:**

The code I use for this seems to have no effect, although it works to remove the default menu items.

---

**The Code:**

```php
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'misha_remove_my_account_links' );
function misha_remove_my_account_links( $menu_links ){

    unset( $menu_links['wc-smart-coupons'] );

    return $menu_links;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already tried to print the `$menu_links` to debug it?

```php
function misha_remove_my_account_links( $menu_links ) {
    // debug purposes, print the array to make it visual
    echo '<pre>', print_r($menu_links, 1), '</pre>';

    //unset( $menu_links['wc-smart-coupons'] );

    return $menu_links;
}
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'misha_remove_my_account_links', 10, 1 );
```

---

EDIT:

Disable the following

> WooCommerce - Settings - Smart Coupons - Show coupons available to customers on their My account > coupons page

Seems to be sufficient